# React JS onClick change what is being rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, onclick, react-redux

The user enters and name and I map out a list of users based on the search criteria. The results are ordered by rank:

```
(resultsOrder = rank.map(id => results.get(id))
```

For each result the users pic, firstname and last name are displayed along with an Add Button (as only people who aren't friends are displayed). Once this button is pressed, the friendship is added to the database.

However onClick I also want the button to change from:

```
<Button name="Add" style="blue" onClick={() => addFriend(userId, r.user_id)} />
```

to:

```
<p> - Request Sent - </p>
```

But I don't know how to change just one of the buttons in the map loop?

**Example,**

=> *Search results are displayed:*

Bob Smith     **ADD**

Bob Smithies  **ADD**

=> *After Bob Smith is pressed:*

Bob Smith    **- Request Sent -**

Bob Smithies   **ADD**

---

If this isn't easily possible: removing the specific result from the list after they have been added but displaying an alert("friend request sent") before would be acceptable.

---

```
rank: List(...)
  0: "3"
  1: "2"
  2: "1"
  3: "4"

results: Map(...)
   0: Array[2]
     0: "2"
     1: Record(...)
        0: Array[2]
           0: "user_id"
           1: "2"
        1: Array[2]
           0: "firstName"
           1: "Bob"
        2: Array[2]
           0: "lastName"
           1: "Smith"
   ...
```

---

```
class ShowResults extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
      this.state = {}
}

  render() {
    const { inviteFriend, results, rank, userId, addFriend } = this.props

    const resultsOrdered = rank.map(id => results.get(id))

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              {resultsOrdered.map(
                (r, friendId) =>
                  (
                    <tr key={r.user_id}>
                      <td>
                        <img src={r.picUrl} />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {r.firstName} {r.lastName}
                      </td>
                       <Button name="Add" style="blue" onClick={() => addFriend(userId, r.user_id)} />
                    </tr>
                  )
               )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      ) 
    }
  }

  export default ShowResults
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In handler, you can update your list to update the button text.
>
> Based on my understanding, I have tried creating below snippet. Hope this helps.

```js
const list = [
  {
    name: "Bob Smith",
    id:1
  },
  {
    name: "Martin Cooper",
    id:2
  },
  {
    name: "Bob Smithies",
    id:3
  },
  {
    name: "David",
    id:4
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: list
    };
    this.addFriend = this.addFriend.bind(this);
  }
  
  some() {
    console.log("done:")
  }

  addFriend(item) {
    let updatedList = this.state.list.map(obj => {
       if(obj.id === item.id) {
         return Object.assign({}, obj, {
            updatedLabel: "Request Sent"
         });
       }
       return obj;
    });
    this.setState({
      list : updatedList
    }, () => {
      this.some()
    });
  }
  
  addFriendAndHide(item) {
    let updatedList = this.state.list.filter(obj => {
         if(obj.id === item.id) {
           return false;
         }
         return true;
      });
    this.setState({
      list : updatedList
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.list.map(item =>
              <tr key={item.itemId}>
                <td>
                  {item.name}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    className="delete"
                    onClick={() => this.addFriend(item)}
                  >
                    {item.updatedLabel || "Add"}
                  </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    className="delete"
                    onClick={() => this.addFriendAndHide(item)}
                  >
                    {"Hide after request is sent"}
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
table td {
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: normal;
     padding: 10px;
     border: 1px solid #eee;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

**Update:**

Yes you can do call any fn after the state changes async as below:

```
this.setState({
  ...      //update label by updating list
}, ()=> {
   this.addFriend()
});
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I had in mind, thanks. Just finding it hard to merge in with my stuff.

Comment: I would like to keep my addFriend() as is please as it calls a php file. Can I not add another () where I simply just change the label? e.g. onClick={() => addFriend(userId, r.userId) && changeLabel()}

Comment: @H1ggsy, you can call other fn in aysnc after state changes. Updated the answer. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I play around with it a bit and managed to get this to work to near enough what I need. Thank you.

Comment: However this was for removing the item (filter), I could get the button text to change but the picUrl and name disappeared?